# Limit of a particular sum?

Tags: integration, limits

From Gradshtyen and Ryzhik, 2.111(3), for $t$ real and $\alpha$ a real constant, the indefinite integral
$$f\left( {t;\alpha } \right) = \int {dt\left( {\frac{{{t^n}}}{{t + \frac{1}{\alpha }}}} \right)}  = \frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}}}{{{\alpha ^n}}}\ln \left( {t + \frac{1}{\alpha }} \right) + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - k}}{t^k}}}{{k\,{\alpha ^{n - k}}}}}$$
The integral implies that
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\alpha  \to 0} f\left( {t;\alpha } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\alpha  \to 0} \int {dt\frac{{\alpha {t^n}}}{{\alpha t + 1}}}  = 0$$
Is there any way of finding the equivalent limit for the sum without recognizing the integral form?

Answer (score 1):

Your first expression is false. What is true is that
$$f\left(t;\alpha\right) = \int dt\left( \frac{t^n}{t + \frac 1\alpha}\right)  = \frac{\left(- 1\right)^n}{\alpha ^n}\ln\left|t + \frac 1\alpha\right| + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n - k}t^k}{k\,\alpha^{n - k}} \color{red}{+ C}$$

Indefinite integrals are only defined up to an *arbitrary* constant. We do not know the value of $C$. The value of $C$ is not even defined by the information given.

Actually, even this is not entirely true. The integral is improper at $t = - 1/\alpha$. Indeed, $|f|$ is infinite at this point. The value of $C$ could be different for $t < -1/\alpha$ than it is for $t > -1/\alpha$, since $f$ is already discontinuous there.

And finally, $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \left[\frac{\left(- 1\right)^n}{\alpha ^n}\ln\left|t + \frac 1\alpha\right| + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n - k}t^k}{k\,\alpha^{n - k}}\right] = \pm\infty$$

not $0$. The sign depends on the value of $n$ and on whether $\alpha$ is approaching $0$ from above or below.

Comment: You can take that one up with Gradtshyen and Rhyzik, but my money is on them and their 10000 or so integral fomulae.

Comment: If they actually said that, and you just haven't misinterpreted or miscopied them, then I would gladly take that bet. Constants of integration are basic calculus. Apparently this is a handbook? Then you might try reading the introduction to the section, where I am sure they explained about this, and mention that they don't bother to show the $+C$, since everyone knows it should always be there for indefinite integrals.

Comment: To me, it is the mother of all integral handbooks (much more comprehensive than something like Abramowitz and Stegen); and no, I haven't miscopied or misinterpreted them.  Indeed, it is not difficult to rederive the result using repeated integration by parts; and yes, both they and I understand that the constant of integration is implied, and the subsequent application (that I don't discuss for brevity) is in a definite integral where it is always guaranteed that t+1/alpha is always >= 0.

Comment: And, as an aside in 10+ years of using it, I have found not more than two errors.

Comment: If $t + 1/\alpha > 0$, and you are actually doing a definite integral, neither of which you mentioned in your post (in fact, you said indefinite integral there), what are you whining about? Under those conditions, I have not in any way contradicted your holy bible. I was pointing out flaws in YOUR work, not theirs. And those flaws are real. Your limit calculation is wrong (if $\alpha \to \infty$ instead of $0$, it would be correct). And even if that were corrected, your limit of an indefinite integral would be an arbitrary constant $C$, not $0$.

Comment: I should add that I came across the question when exploring how to properly handle alpha=0, where it is crystal clear from the application that the proper answer to the definite integral must be zero.  But after I thought about it a little, it was unclear how the solution would lead to that, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: By the way, I am not whining, I am trying to get a useful answer to my question.  Unfortunately, yours provides no real insight.

Comment: If you claim that pointing out that your question is ill-posed and that the limit you claim is $0$ is in fact $\pm\infty$ "no real insight", And get huffy that I contradicted your wonderful resource without bothering to notice that I did not contradict it at all, then sorry, but you are whining, not thinking.